# How do I fix this error “execv() arg 2 must contain only strings” in OpenERP 7 webkit report?

Tags: webkit, wkhtmltopdf, openerp-7

We're using OpenERP 7.0 in Ubuntu Server 12.04 and we have installed following modules:

- report_webkit
- account_financial_report_webkit
- account_financial_report_webkit_xls

When we press the "PRINT" button this error occurs:

```
execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

But when push button "EXPORT TO EXCEL" it runs ok.

We have installed wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.1.2

Could you help us?

Answer (score 0):

We have this problem too. Is happening when the command used in subprocess.call, has a parameter with unicode encoded characters.

I've managed to solve it by changing system locale and restarting Odoo/OpenERP.

By default the locale is set as shown:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

By changing it to an UTF8 compatible locale the error is not happening anymore.

```
LANG=es_ES.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.utf8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.utf8
LC_PAPER="es_ES.utf8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already solved. You can check [this fix](https://github.com/martini97/account-financial-reporting/commit/baf5a6681cd33f8554f54bb5c9445a9582abc86c) on OCA Git Hub. You just should update the `account_financial_report_webkit` module with the new commits. The pull request was not made in the OpenERP 7 version, so maybe you should copy the code manually or wait for the pull-request.

Another solution (workaround) is to [change the system variable LANG](https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-reporting/issues/57#issuecomment-118254037): `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`